# How to unscrew a broken washing machine filter cap?

Tags: plumbing

The plastic cap on my washing machine filter was stuck so I applied a little too much force when unscrewing it and its handle broke. Any idea what tools to use to remove it?

The washing machine is a Whilrpool AWE 4526.

[image]

Comment: It looks like there are still some tabs left a heavy duty pair of needle nose pliers held open while turning may grab enough to unscrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a piece of pipe sized to fit into the center part and cut a slot in it with a hacksaw to fit the plastic where the handle was. Then you could use a pair of channel lock pliers to turn the pipe if you need to.

Good luck.